# Null value in Angular Reactive form nested FormGroup

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

I have an angular reactive form with a nested form group

```
this.form = new FormGroup({
  name: new FormControl(),
  address: new FormGroup({
    line1: new FormControl(),
    line2: new FormControl()
  })
});
```

If I call form.patchValue with an object containing the nested fields everything works fine as expected:

```
this.form.patchValue({
    name: 'test',
    address: {
      line1: 'test line 1',
      line2: 'test line 2'
    }
  });
```

However if the address property is null:

```
this.form.patchValue({
    name: 'test',
    address: null
  });
```

I receive an error: Cannot convert undefined or null to object.

How can I get round this problem as the object returned from the server is valid and I have no control over it.

Example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-broncz

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say you get an object from your server that you cannot control, so you don't know if address will have a value or not. You can use the `||` (or) operator for that.

You can also reset the form just in case, depending on how you are using this. If form is not editable before `patchValue`, there would be no need to reset.

```ts
// faking server response
const myObj = { name: 'mytest', address: null };

this.form.reset();
this.form.patchValue({
  name: myObj.name,
  address: myObj.address || {}
});
```

**[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4ckygy?file=src/app/app.component.ts)**

Answer (score 2):

You can reset the control:

```
  setForm2() {
    this.form.controls['address'].reset()
    this.form.patchValue({
        name: 'test'
      });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just give address an empty Object. That throws no error on Stackblitz and only updates what you like.

```
setForm2() {
    this.form.patchValue({
        name: 'test',
        address: {}
      });
  }
```