# Nullable nested FormGroup in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have a FormGroup which has a nested FormGroup which I would like to be able to set to null:

```
this.myForm = formBuilder.group<MyForm>({
  foo: formBuilder.nonNullable.control<string>(''),
  group: new FormGroup<MyGroupForm | null>({
    bar: formBuilder.nonNullable.control('')
  })
});
```

Whenever I try to set the group to null like this:

```
this.myForm.setValue({
  foo: 'foo',
  group: null
});
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'bar')
  at forms.mjs:1594:18
  at forms.mjs:2818:24
  at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
  at FormGroup._forEachChild (forms.mjs:2813:36)
  at assertAllValuesPresent (forms.mjs:1593:13)
  at FormGroup.setValue (forms.mjs:2670:9)
  at forms.mjs:2673:33
  at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
  at FormGroup.setValue (forms.mjs:2671:28)
  at new AppComponent (app.component.ts:27:17)
```

This is not a duplicate of this question: [Null value in Angular Reactive form nested FormGroup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58647639/null-value-in-angular-reactive-form-nested-formgroup) because I want intentionally set the group to null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a [known issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/20509) since 2017 !

I [proposed a PR recently](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/48830), let see where this is going !

Comment: any workarounds? The one in the issues seems outdated.

Comment: @Matthieu isn't this setting the controllers inside the form group to null? , I am trying to set the FormGroup itself to null, is that possible ?